# Are there pre-computed tables for values of the "sum-of-divisors" function?

Tags: divisor-sum, reference-works

Let $\sigma$ denote the "sum-of-divisors" function, i.e.,

$${\displaystyle \sigma _{}(n)=\sum _{d\mid n}d^{}\,\!.}$$

Note that the sequence $\sigma(n)$, for $n\geq1$ is in the OEIS as entry [A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203). Unfortunately, that entry does not contain any reference to values of $\sigma$ for larger $n$. Where can I find tables for the values of $\sigma$ for large values (i.e., $n\geq10^{10}$)?

Do such tables exist, like for primes?

Comment: Are you interested in particular ranges, or just which ranges have been calculated by someone ?

Comment: @Peter Everything larger than $10^{10}$ interest me.